# using Bulk amount of data through out the MVC session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, caching

I have to use a bulk amount of data through out the session for each user in MVC application (data is user specific)

Below are the two method I found it

1. Use a session object load the data into it and retrieve when ever needed
2. Create a XML file into the disk and retrieve the data when ever required

which one of the above is good for a web application? 
If both are not good please let me know a convenient method.

I read about caching but that also take the memory concern as Session or not?

Please help me with simple example if anyone has gone through the same.

Answer (score 0):

I will not go with any of the approaches you highlighted, both the approaches will give you problems and code modification will be required when you plan to scale you application and try to move to load balancer or web farm type of environment.

You should try to make your application as much stateless as possible.

You can store the data in database, if your tables are properly indexed it will not take much time to fetch the data (almost same as fetching data from a xml file).

If the data is not sensitive and you requires it in client side only, you can think of storing it into `sessionStorage`

Comment: due to some issue database connection taking long time and affecting system perfomance..need to remove database hiting

Comment: Sessionstorage  for each user will consume high amount of memory

Comment: but session storage will be at client side for each individual user, so there will be no impact on memory of the application if the no of users increases.

Comment: What database you are using and which version?

Comment: Oracle 11 i..it was fine tille couple of month ago..now connection is taking more than 20-50 seconds each time from the application..some time we are getting timeout exception..

Comment: database administrators are working on the same..but till no solution..so im looking for a different approach for this to be solved bcos of end users are not able to use the same

Comment: Ideally you should try fix the db issue, doing the above changes will lead to more problems later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169018/discussion-between-sachu-and-psk).